# Aligning Summation

Tags: align

[image]

I am trying to align each "+" sign and also each term, where if a term is shorter, then it is aligned in the middle. For example, a_3 would go directly above and in the middle of a_{n_2}. How would I do this?

```
\begin{align*} 
S_n &= &(a_1) &+ (a_2)     &+ &(a_3)     &+ \cdots + (a_1+[n-1]d)\\ 
S_n &= &(a_n) &+ (a_{n-1}) &+ &(a_{n-2}) &+ \cdots + (a_n+[n-1]d)
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `array`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c *{10}{@{\;}c}}
S_n &=& (a_1) &+& (a_2)     &+& (a_3)     &+& \cdots &+& (a_1+[n-1]d)\\ 
S_n &=& (a_n) &+& (a_{n-1}) &+& (a_{n-2}) &+& \cdots &+& (a_n+[n-1]d)
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am also a little confused. What does & mean? Does that just align the corresponding things?

Comment: The ampersand is use in table to change to the next column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that  with `alignat*`, which inserts no space between alignment columns, combined with `eqparbox`, which defines  box commands like the standard ones, with a difference: they use a system of tags in the place of a width argument, and all boxes sharing the same tag have as width the natural width of the widest contents. Note this may require two compilations to adjust the widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox} 
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$#2$}}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
S_n &=\eqmathbox[1]{(a_1)} &&+\eqmathbox[2]{(a_2)} & & + \eqmathbox[3]{(a_3)} & & + \dots + (\eqmathbox[n-1]{a_1}+[n-1]d)\\
S_n &=\eqmathbox[1]{(a_n)}& &+ \eqmathbox[2]{(a_{n-1})} & & +\eqmathbox[3]{(a_{n-2})} & & + \dots + (\eqmathbox[n-1]{a_n}+[n-1]d)
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]